# Full Page Cache in our Cluster users are able to see other users accounts

Tags: full-page-cache, enterprise-1.13, redis, loadbalancing

When I turn on Full Page Cache in our Cluster users are able to see other users accounts.

We are using REDIS for Objects and FPC now (Separate instances)
I switch sessions to the database
We have 4 web heads and one database server
Magento Enterprise 1.13.1
Use SID on Frontend is set to **NO**
**NOTE:** I am using two different REDIS instances on two different ports. I XX'd out the url and the port number. The problem IS NOT with REDIS as we had this same problem with storing via FILES and with a different theme

I confirmed I was getting traffic to the FPC REDIS instance (We are using Object Rocket)

```
   <session_save><![CDATA[db]]></session_save>
    <cache>
       <backend><![CDATA[Mage_Cache_Backend_Redis]]></backend>
        <backend_options>
        <server><![CDATA[xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.rackspaceclouddb.com]]></server>
       <port><![CDATA[xxx12]]></port>
        <database><![CDATA[0]]></database>
        <password>LikeIWillPublishthePassword</password>
       <force_standalone><![CDATA[0]]></force_standalone>
       <automatic_cleaning_factor><![CDATA[0]]></automatic_cleaning_factor> 
      <compress_data><![CDATA[1]]></compress_data>
      <compress_tags><![CDATA[1]]></compress_tags> 
      <compress_threshold><![CDATA[20480]]></compress_threshold>
      <compression_lib><![CDATA[gzip]]></compression_lib>
     <lifetimelimit><![CDATA[43200]]></lifetimelimit>
    </backend_options>
    </cache>
```

Here is the added XML for the Enterprise FPC

```
<config>
    <global>
        <cache>
            <request_processors>
                <ee>Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Processor</ee>
            </request_processors>
            <frontend_options>
                <slab_size>1040000</slab_size>
            </frontend_options>
        </cache>
        <full_page_cache>
            <backend>Mage_Cache_Backend_Redis</backend>
            <backend_options>
            <server>7xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxublb.rackspaceclouddb.com</server>  
              <port>xxxxxxxx31</port>
              <persistent></persistent>                 
           <database>0</database>  
               <password>SomePassword</password>
              <force_standalone>0</force_standalone>
              <connect_retries>1</connect_retries>    
              <lifetimelimit>57600</lifetimelimit> 
              <compress_data>0</compress_data>
            </backend_options>
         </full_page_cache>
    </global>
</config>
```

(I used the Inchoo Example for FPC)

Please let me know if I forgot something. The only thing that I could think of is if the web heads didn't get all the relevant XML after we published the new enterprise file

**EDIT FROM CLIENT:**

> I just first noticed on the home page but I was actually able to click
>   on on /customer/account  and see the other person's recent orders

Comment: What kind of content are they seeing? Could you also post your cache.xml file contents?  It sounds like the cache key being generated for individual container blocks doesn't have enough uniqueness.

Comment: We have users who are seeing other users accounts. All my cache xml files are posted. Perhaps I am missing one that you would like to see?

Comment: What is an example URL and what content do they see?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but isn't customer account page excluded from FPC by default? Also HTTPS? Are you sure FPC is not modded in any way?

Comment: This a core version of Magento - We installed a new theme but the same issue happened on the old theme. I just opened a ticket with Magento

Comment: @KevinSchroeder my client reported they noticed on the home page. It said Welcome [Wrong Name]

Comment: @jharrison.au These are two separate instances of REDIS. If you notice the url and the ports are different. Your FPC example is the standard FPC that comes with Magento. Your class on your Object cache is the old CM class.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue on 1.11 but with "accountLinks" block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento support found the answer: the problem

CE themes on EE installs and all of them were related to templates. The CE block doesn't have an FPC placeholder, so it will be cached one time and will be shared before other customers.

The code should be moved into an independent block and named as "welcome".

According to the config of the Full Page Cache block "Welcome" has a placeholder which does not cache this block, so that this block is unique per customer.

app/code/core/Enterprise/PageCache/etc/cache.xml (lines 62-67)

```
<welcome_message>
    <block>page/html_welcome</block>
    <placeholder>WELCOME</placeholder>
    <container>Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Container_Welcome</container>
    <cache_lifetime>86400</cache_lifetime>
</welcome_message>
```

For example, in the original template:

app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/page/html/header.phtml (lines 31-35)

```
<div class="header-panel">
    <div class="switches"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('switches') ?></div>
    <p class="welcome-msg"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('welcome') ?></p>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('accountLinks') ?>
</div>
```

i.e. the welcome block is used as a child of the header's block, because
app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/layout/page.xml (lines 71-88)

```
 <block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
 <block type="page/template_links" name="account.links" as="accountLinks"/>
                ...
 <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="top.container" as="topContainer" translate="label">
  <label>Page Header</label>
  <action method="setElementClass"><value>top-container</value></action>
  </block>
  <block type="page/html_welcome" name="welcome" as="welcome"/>
    </block>
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be any number of things but here's a list of possibilities to rule out:

1. Ensure any custom blocks are being added to the Enterprise_PageCache config as follows:

   ```
   <!-- My_Module/etc/cache.xml -->  
   <config>  
       <placeholders>  
           <cart_sidebar>  
               <block>custom_module/cart_sidebar</block>
               <placeholder>CART_SIDEBAR</placeholder>
               <container>Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Container_Sidebar_Cart</container>
               <cache_lifetime>86400</cache_lifetime>
           </cart_sidebar>
       </placeholders>
   </config>
   ```
2. Ensure no third party services are caching HTML (services like Squixa sometimes accelerate websites this way)
3. Try disabling APC or Zend OPcache if one is enabled (recently had some issues with this)

Comment: Neither of these provide an answer. You can see that I have different URLs and ports for REDIS and you examples don't include REDIS. You CM_CACHE is an old version of the XML. Your FPC example does not address using REDIS.

Comment: Yep you're right, I misread your config. My config does result in using Redis however, as the backend gets overwritten in `local.xml`. Have you heard back from Enterprise support?

Comment: Magento is doing a SSH Screen share sessions to diagnose the problem. I will post there results when they are done